# How to conveniently explore docker log file?

Tags: docker

I have a container that generates millions of logs and in order to address a bug, I need to find something in these logs, I might need to apply filtration by data-time of the logs and by specific keywords in the logs..

What's an out-of-the-box way to do this, or maybe to convert the file into CSV format so I can apply such queries from Microsoft Excel

Answer (score 0):

Docker has multiple log drivers: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

You could for example redirect it to journald and then check logs with journalctl or you can even redirect to splunk or fluentd.